# I want to use ROS, with the ViSP package in an Odroid XU4 running Ubuntu 15.04, is that possible?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am part of a research group and we are interested in doing servo vision with an Odroid XU4, the board will be running Ubuntu 15.04. The question is if we will be able to install ROS with ViSP on that board.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/260629/i-want-to-use-ros,-with-the-visp-package-in-an-odroid-xu4-running-ubuntu-15.04,-is-that-possible?/) by [macaroli270](https://answers.ros.org/users/30200/macaroli270/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-04-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's certainly should be possible. ROS Jade has been tested on Vivid (15.04).

However since Vivid has reached it's End-Of-Life there's no active support for it from Ubuntu/Canonical or from the ROS community.

Furthermore it will require a lot of patience as binaries are not available for ARM architecture on Vivid so you will need to compile from source.

I would strongly recommend considering using a currently supported Ubuntu distro. Such as Xenial 16.04. And then you'll find ROS Kinetic packages available for the Odroid including visp: http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_kinetic_uxv8.html?q=visp

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-04-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [macaroli270](https://answers.ros.org/users/30200/macaroli270/) on 2017-05-10**:
Thanks for your answer!

I will try with 16.04 :)